# Static routing - Gateway blocking ping packets

Tags: networking, routing, ping, gateway

Here is my situation.

I have 2 Windows 10 PCs and one Linux PC that I will use as a gateway to route traffic between the two Windows PCs.

Windows PC1: 131.180.21.124, Linux PC: 131.180.21.114

Windows PC2: 131.180.145.20

PC1 and Linux machines are on the same subnet and PC2 on a different one.
All 3 machines can ping each others. Now I add the below static route on Windows PC1:

**route add 131.180.145.20 mask 255.255.255.255 131.180.21.114**

Now the ping from Windows PC1 to PC2 begins to time out. When I run Wireshark on all 3 machines to find out the bottleneck, I observe that the ping packets reach Linux gateway from PC1, but PC2 does not receive them. So it seems that the Linux machine is unable to forward the ping request to PC2. Is there an explanation to this behavior? Please share ideas on how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is LinuxPC connected to WindowsPC2? (Gateways generally have at least two interfaces and at least two IP addresses, one for each...) Is gateway mode (IP forwarding) actually _enabled_ on it via sysctl?

Comment: LinuxPC uses it's default gateway (131.180.20.1.) to connect to WindowsPC2. I only have one NIC on the Linux gateway!

Comment: You said that WinPC2 doesn't receive the forwarded packets, but according to Wireshark, does the LinuxPC _send_ them? Does the gateway (131.180.20.1) itself know how to reach WinPC2? And again is the IP forwarding sysctl enabled on LinuxPC?

Comment: Wireshark on LinuxPC shows "Echo(ping) .... (no response)". So I am assuming that it is dispatching the packets but WindowsPC2 is not receiving it. LinuxPC can independently ping WindowsPC2, so it's gateway is aware of the path to WindowsPC2.

Comment: Another strange thing: When I run "sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" on LinuxPC, the defined static route is bypassed and the default route (destination: 0.0.0.0) is taken to reach WindowsPC2.

Comment: Additionally, can using a single adapter for receiving and forwarding be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the root cause is that you expect routes to predefine the entire path from start to finish, while in reality they're hop-by-hop...

Comment: Once the packets reach the LinuxPC, aren't they supposed to take the usual route to WindowsPC2?They both are certainly accessible from each other as confirmed by independent ping tests.

Comment: They are... but "the usual route" in this case is the the default route, isn't it? (And since WinPC1 and LinuxPC are in the same subnet, it just happens to be the same gateway as if it would have been in the direct path...)

Comment: Yes, "the usual route" in my statement refers to the default route between LinuxPC and WinPC2. However, although WinPC1 and LinuxPC are both in the same subnet, the default route from WinPC1 to WinPC2 does not include LinuxPC, unlike our custom defined route.

Comment: So how do you know that the route `WinPC1->gateway->WinPC2` is being taken, rather than `WinPC1->LinuxPC->gateway->WinPC2`?

Comment: I am assuming that you are now talking about this comment of mine: "Another strange thing: When I run "sysctl .....". I can see through tracert command when ip_forward=1 is set, default route is taken. Otherwise, the LinuxPC receives ping requests.

Comment: A setting in one PC cannot possibly change the route chosen by another PC...

Comment: The setting is in LinuxPC which is the custom gateway. Now if the setting makes it impossible to work as a gateway then the OS falls back to default route. Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96399/discussion-between-vigo-and-grawity).